# Manage handlers in web.config for different environments

Tags: configuration, deployment

I removed some of the handlers on root web.config and place it on the subfolder sitecore/web.config but it looks like the handlers on subfolder is not working.

Here's the content of sitecore/web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Sitecore.FeedRequestHandler" verb="*" path="sitecore_feed.ashx" type="Sitecore.Shell.Feeds.FeedRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      <add name="Sitecore.SimulationRequestHandler" verb="*" path="sitecore_device_simulation.ashx" type="Sitecore.Shell.DeviceSimulation.SimulationRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel"  />
      <add name="Sitecore.WebDAVMediaRequestHandler" verb="*" path="sitecore_webDAV.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.WebDAVMediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_expeditor_speak_request.ashx" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak" name="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak" />
      <add name="WebDAVRoot" path="*" verb="OPTIONS,PROPFIND" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
      <add name="WebDAVRoot64" path="*" verb="OPTIONS,PROPFIND" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
      <add verb="*" name="Sitecore.SpeakJS64" path="*/speak/v1/*/*.js" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
      <add verb="*" name="Sitecore.SpeakJS32" path="*/speak/v1/*/*.js" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
      <add verb="*" name="Sitecore.SpeakClassic64" path="sitecore_speak.ashx" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
      <add verb="*" name="Sitecore.SpeakClassic32" path="sitecore_speak.ashx" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_speak.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Scripts.ScriptHandler, Sitecore.Speak.Client" name="Sitecore.Speak" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing. Hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by moving the handler definitions? And what is not working?

Comment: Hi @DanSinclair, those list of handler was intended only for CM and i want to remove them from CD that's why i want to place them on subfolder sitecore/web.config.

And when i moved them on sitecore/web.config, they are not working anymore when i'm trying to access the sitecore client.

Comment: As per my understanding, patch file will not work for Web.config items. It will work for Sitecore specific items. Handlers entry utilize by the ASP.net engine on initialisation of application.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use SlowCheetah or similar tool to transform web.config and add/remove parts based on environment that you are deploying to.

You can also use another approach where you have separate folder structure for every environment with all specific web.config and you deploy only that one file based on target and matched folder name.